Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User.getAttribute(String)" because "oauthUser" is null
Spring OAuth2 name is always null. I am trying to implement 'Login with Google' in Spring Boot. I have already implemented JWT token functionality.
im also face same issue in Login with google. anyone have solution? i follow same step
    @GetMapping("/loginSuccess")
public String loginSuccess(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User oauthUser) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Authentication principal: " + authentication.getPrincipal());

    if (oauthUser == null) {
        return "Error: OAuth2User is null. Authentication failed.";
    }
    String username = oauthUser.getAttribute("name");
    JwtToken jwtToken = jwtUtils.generateTokenFromUsername(username);
    return "Login successful! JWT Token: " + jwtToken;
}

here my SecurityConfig
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers(
                                antMatcher("/api/auth/**"),
                                antMatcher("/oauth2/**"),
                                antMatcher("/login/**")
                        ).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/auth/loginSuccess")
                    .failureUrl("/api/auth/loginFailure")
            )
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    return http.build();

ERROR:
Authentication principal: anonymousUser
2024-11-07T11:25:56.555+05:30 ERROR 12772 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User.getAttribute(String)" because "oauthUser" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User.getAttribute(String)" because "oauthUser" is null
    at com.wisedoctor.security.controllers.AuthController.loginSuccess(AuthController.java:279) ~[classes/:na]


Don't use this
String username = oauthUser.getAttribute("name"); // This line cause NullPointer exception.

Let's use
Authentication.getPrincipal()

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/user/OAuth2User.html

Im already try this
"Authentication.getPrincipal()" because "authentication" is null"- In my working project.
then i try this on Demo project it work
"Login successful! User: Ahamed, Email: rizha318@gmail.com"
some how my real project cant get user details(use same credential). I'm already use JWT to authenticate. Now I'm try to optional login(email password && sign in with google)
